# Cometd vs ActiveMQ for server side push for real time web applications

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, comet, server-push, cometd

We have requirement to develop server side push infra for real time web applications. For this, I have been considering using Cometd since this supports both long polling as well as web sockets based implementation.

However, I recently came across links like http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html and http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html that say even ActiveMQ provides support for server side push using long polling(Comet technique) as well as web sockets. My understanding is that ActiveMQ implementation for this does not conform to Bayeux protocol.

Is there any advantage/benefits of ActiveMQ over the Cometd for server side push solutions? Are there any additional features that one of these provide? Which is these is more popular and stable?

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the primary reason to choose ActiveMQ is when you are building backend technology based on messaging in the first place. Then you can very easy get up and running by pushing messages to browsers.

Still, I don't really think ActiveMQ was really inteded to be a glue technology between backend and front-end, so it may be an odd bird to make it fit into the general case (although, I must admit, I have not tried).

Comment: Thanks Petter. It's possible that because ActiveMQ was not initially implemented with server push for web apps in mind, it is not yet a popular or heavily advertized server push technology. In fact most forums that discuss  many server push technologies and Comet implementations don't even mention ActiveMQ as one of the options. So, I am wondering if I should just get started with CometD.